# Get Url value for a multitenant application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a multi tenant application, which will share the same db. The tenants are authenticated by tenant id based on subdomain.

Each user have separate subdomain to access the app

> for eg: user1 = test.example.com and User2 = test2.example.com

I would like to know what is the best approach to fetch the url they are accessing the app from.

> For example say the user accessed the app like this
>   http://test1.example.com/
>
> I would like to fecth just "test1.example.com".

I am currently using this

```
string[] host = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Host"].Split(':');
```

Can anyone suggest the best way to do it ?

Comment: Use this property? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.authority(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hi @starlight54, thanks for the help, but not what I am looking for, I made an edit, please refer to it.

Comment: That method seems perfect to me, the Host Header is required in HTTP 1.1 which I'm assuming your using :P Alternative would be to use Request.RawUrl and go from there but it's probably a worse method if anything. I guess you want .First() on the end too :D